# Finding number of solutions of 2 simultaneous equations.

Tags: number-theory, logarithms

> There are 2 equations
>   $x^2+y^3=29$ and $\log_3x.\log_2y=1$.
>   Find the number of solutions in $x$ and $y$ where $x,y \in \Bbb R$

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I had multiple approaches like putting value of x in terms of y in other equation. Simplifying 2nd equation or hit and trial method to find a link. None of them turned fruitful. I didn't try graphical method though but that seems trivial solution for this question

Comment: Try graphing your two equations. It may give you an idea of what you are looking for.

Comment: This is an ugly problem, only a numerical solution is possible. After setting $x=3^u$, $y=2^{1/u}$ we have to solve $f(u):=3^{2u}+2^{3/u}-29=0$, $f$ is convex, $f(1/2)=38>0$, $f(1)=-12<0$, $f(3/2)=2>0$, so we expect a solution between $1/2$ and $1$, and an other one between $1$ and $3/2$, pari/gp delivers for `solve( u=0.1,1, 3^(2*u)+2^(3/u) - 29 )` the result `0.64718824239603875658029040340778233317` and for ` `solve( u=1,1.5, 3^(2*u)+2^(3/u) - 29 )` the result 1.4623174037485863183265033005868559095 ...

Comment: @dan_fulea- you may write the answer. By graphical method it has 2 solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the second equation as
$$ \ln x\cdot \ln y=\ln 2\cdot \ln 3.$$
To even speak about logs, we need $x,y$ to be positive. Also, $\ln2\ln3$ is positive hence either both $x,y$ are $<1$ r both are $>1$. The first option makes $x^2+y^3<2$ and is rejected. We conclude $1<x<\sqrt{28}$. We can eliminate $y$ using the first equation  to arrive at 
$$ \ln x\cdot\ln\sqrt[3]{29-x^2}=\ln 2\ln3$$
or
$$ \ln x^2\cdot \ln(29-x^2)=6\ln2\ln3.$$
With $z:=x^2-\frac{29}2$ (ranging from $-\frac{27}2$ to $\frac{27}2$ as $x$ ranges from $1$ to $\sqrt{28}$), this equation is of the form
$$\tag1f(z)f(-z)=c $$
where $f(z)=\ln(z+\frac{29}2)$ is a strictly increasing function. 
The solutions of $(1)$ are symmetric around $0$. Numerically, we verify that for $z=0$, the left hand side is greater than the right hand side.
On the other hand, $f(-\frac{27}2)=0$ so that  we conclude from the intermediate value theorem that there is at least one solution with $z\in(0,\frac{27}2)$.
Assume there are two positive solutions of $(1)$.
Then by Rolle, there must be an intermediate (hence also positive) point where the derivative of the left hand side is $=0$, i.e., for some $z\in(0,\frac{27}2)$,
$$ f'(z)f(-z)=f(z)f'(-z)$$
i.e.,
$$ \frac{\ln(-z+\frac{29}2)}{z+\frac{29}2}=\frac{\ln(z+\frac{29}2)}{-z+\frac{29}2}$$
or $ g(-z)=g(z)$
where $g(z)=(z+\frac{29}2)\ln(z+\frac{29}2)$ . In the range in question, $g$ is strictly increasing (product of positive increasing functions), hence $g(-z)=g(z)$ has only one solution, and that is the trivial solution $z=0$.

We conclude that $(1)$ and thereby the original equation system has exactly

> **two**

solutions in the range considered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution from dan fulea.

This is an ugly problem, only a numerical solution is possible.
After setting $x=3u, y=21/u$ we have to solve $f(u):=32u+23/u−29=0$,
$f$ is convex, $f(1/2)=38>0$, $f(1)=−12<0$, $f(3/2)=2>0$, so we expect a solution between $1/2$ and $1$, and an other one between $1$ and $3/2$,
$pari/gp$ delivers for solve
$( u=0.1,1, 3^{(2*u)}+2^{(3/u)} - 29 )$ the result $0.64718824239603875658029040340778233317$
and  for other solve
$( u=1,1.5, 3^{(2*u)}+2^{(3/u)} - 29 )$ the result $1.4623174037485863183265033005868559095$ ...